# Syncfusion MVC Datagrid - how to display button in row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, syncfusion

I have a Syncfusion MVC Datagrid and I need to display a custom button in each row to take some action. The **Employee Details** column is cut and pasted from their website: https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/grid/columns?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=razor

VS error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a
>   delegate type

What is the correct syntax to make the button appear?

Also, I will need correct jscript/controller code to callback the controller and get back the ID or selected item.

```
@Html.EJS().Grid("DataGrid").DataSource(ds => ds.Json(ViewBag.datasource).UpdateUrl("/Management/Update").InsertUrl("/Management/Insert").RemoveUrl("/Management/Remove").Adaptor("RemoteSaveAdaptor")).AllowTextWrap().Columns(col =>
{
col.Field("Id").IsPrimaryKey(true).Visible(false).Add();
col.Field("ResourceGroup").HeaderText("Source VM Resource Group").Add();
col.Field("VMName").HeaderText("Source VM Name").Add();
col.Field("ImageDate").HeaderText("Image Capture Start Date").Width(150).Format("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm").HeaderTextAlign(Syncfusion.EJ2.Grids.TextAlign.Center).EditType("datetimepickeredit").Edit(new { @params = new { min = System.DateTime.UtcNow, showclearbutton = true } }).Add();
col.Field("ImageRecurrance").HeaderText("Image Recurrence (days)").EditType("numericedit").Edit(new { @params = new { min = 0, step = 10, decimals = 0, strictmode = true } }).Width(100).Add();
col.Field("ImageVersion").HeaderText("Image Version").Add();
col.HeaderText("Employee Details").Commands(command =>
    {
    command.Type("detail")
        .ButtonOptions(new Syncfusion.JavaScript.Models.ButtonProperties()
        {
            Text = "Details",
            Width = "100px",
            Click = "onClick"
        }).Add();
})                
.TextAlign(TextAlign.Center)
.Width(150)
.Add();
}).ActionFailure("OnActionFailure").AllowTextWrap(true).TextWrapSettings(text => { text.WrapMode(Syncfusion.EJ2.Grids.WrapMode.Header); }).AllowPaging().FilterSettings(filter => { filter.Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.Grids.FilterType.Menu); }).EditSettings(edit => { edit.AllowAdding(true).AllowEditing(true).AllowDeleting(true).ShowDeleteConfirmDialog(true).Mode(Syncfusion.EJ2.Grids.EditMode.Dialog); }).Toolbar(toolbarItems).TextWrapSettings(text => { text.WrapMode(Syncfusion.EJ2.Grids.WrapMode.Header); }).Render()
```

Comment: have you tried something in js and in controller..so we can get the idea about it

Answer (score 0):

The button is simple with the following Column Template:

- **Management** = Controller
- **Select** = Action
- **${Id}** = value to pass on QueryString

```
<a href='/Management/Select?Id=${Id}'>
    <button class='e-control e-btn e-lib' id='button' type='button'>Related</button>
</a>
```

**Grid Definition**

```
@{int buttonWidth = 160; } 

@Html.EJS().Grid("DataGrid").DataSource(ds => ds.Json(ViewBag.datasource).UpdateUrl("/Management/Update").InsertUrl("/Management/Insert").RemoveUrl("/Management/Remove").Adaptor("RemoteSaveAdaptor")).AllowTextWrap().Columns(col =>
{

    col.Field("Id").IsPrimaryKey(true).Visible(false).Add();
    col.Field("RG").HeaderText("RG").Width(@colWidth).Add();
    col.Template("<a href='/Management/Select?Id=${Id}'><button class='e-control e-btn e-lib' id='button' type='button'>Related</button></a>").AllowEditing(false).Width(@buttonWidth).Add();

}).ActionFailure("OnActionFailure").AllowTextWrap(true).TextWrapSettings(text => { text.WrapMode(Syncfusion.EJ2.Grids.WrapMode.Header); }).AllowPaging().FilterSettings(filter => { filter.Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.Grids.FilterType.Menu); }).EditSettings(edit => { edit.AllowAdding(true).AllowEditing(true).AllowDeleting(true).ShowDeleteConfirmDialog(true).Mode(Syncfusion.EJ2.Grids.EditMode.Dialog); }).Toolbar(toolbarItems).TextWrapSettings(text => { text.WrapMode(Syncfusion.EJ2.Grids.WrapMode.Header); }).Render()
```

**Controller**

```
    public class ManagementController : Controller
    {
...
        public ActionResult Select(object newItem)
        {
              var id = System.Convert.ToInt32(this.Request.QueryString["Id"]);
```